# en un array en java el programa deberá indicar los valores que se repiten y cuantas veces se repiten y en la posición que se encuentran ingresados

Tags: java, array, algoritmos

en un array en java el programa deberá indicar los valores que se repiten y cuantas veces se repiten y en la posición que se encuentran ingresados esto es lo que hice:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] manual = {20,10,40,70,10,60,90,80,10,10,10};
        int[] repetido = new int[10];
        int[] posicion = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < 10; j++) {               
                if (manual[i]==manual[j]){
                    posicion[i]=i;
                    repetido[i]=manual[i];
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (repetido[i]!=0){
                System.out.print("Valor "+repetido[i]+" repetido en la posicion ");
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                    if (posicion[k]!=0) {
                        System.out.print(posicion[k]+", ");
                    }                 
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

el resultado que me da en consola es el siguiente:

```
Valor 10 repetido en la posicion 1, 4, 8, Valor 10 repetido en la posicion 1, 4, 8, Valor 10 repetido en la posicion 1, 4, 8,
```

donde se ve que falta la posicion 9 y 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma menos recursiva de resolver lo que propones sería esta:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] manual = {20,10,40,70,10,60,90,80,10,10,10};

        int repetido = 0;
        int key = 0;
        List < Integer > repetidos = new ArrayList < > ();
        String posicion;
        for (int x = 0; x < manual.length; x++) {
            posicion = "";
            for (int y = 0; y < manual.length && !repetidos.contains(manual[x]); y++) {
                if (manual[x] == manual[y]) {
                    repetido += 1;

                    if (repetido > 1)
                        posicion += new StringBuilder().append(",");

                    posicion += new StringBuilder().append(y);;
                }
            }
            if (repetido > 0) {
                repetidos.add(key, manual[x]);

                if (posicion.length() > 1)
                    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("Valor ").append(repetidos.get(key)).append(", repetido en las posiciones ").append(posicion));

                key++;
            }
            repetido = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado sería : Valor 10, repetido en las posiciones 1,4,8,9,10